# Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT open images and pdf

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to open recent window which will have only image and pdf selectable

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

but in this i can select only image how i can add pdf also

Answer (score 10):

you can do the following using EXTRA_MIME_TYPES (from API 19):

```
final String[] ACCEPT_MIME_TYPES = {
        "application/pdf",
        "image/*"
  };
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, ACCEPT_MIME_TYPES);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

**UPDATE**

There is also another solution but it may or may not work based on users experiences but you can try it to see if it works in your case:

```
intent.setType("image/*,application/pdf");
```

However the application that you try to invoke should also supports to MIME types as well

Comment: Ya. You have to use intent.setType("*/*");

Comment: i tired but it not showing pdf 2nd par in default file browser

Comment: @andro that is probably because the default file browser doesn't support multiple MIME